# Ajax Post no envia datos a una funcion en PHP mediante onclick

Tags: php, jquery

Logré resolver el problema que tenía anteriormente en el que el operador "*in*" no funcionaba. Lo malo es que ahora el ajax no quiere correr.

Este es el pt que contiene el historial:

```
<section id="historialPT" style="display: none;">
<!-- Historial -->
<!-- Volver -->
<a class="btnVovlverDas" href="dashboard.php">
    <img src="images/btnVolver.svg"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
</a>
<!-- Volver -->  
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"><b><?php echo $semanas[0]?></b></div> <!-- Primera seamana -->
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2020-02-28" onclick="Historial('2020-02-28');">D01</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-01-04" onclick="Historial('2016-01-04');">D02</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-10-26" onclick="Historial('2016-10-26');">D03</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-10-27" onclick="Historial('2016-10-27');">D04</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-10-28" onclick="Historial('2016-10-28');">D05</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-10-29" onclick="Historial('2016-10-29');">D06</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-10-30" onclick="Historial('2016-10-30');">D07</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"><b><?php echo $semanas[1]?></b></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-10-31" onclick="Historial('2016-10-31');">D08</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-01" onclick="Historial('2016-11-01');">D09</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-02" onclick="Historial('2016-11-02');">D10</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-03" onclick="Historial('2016-11-03');">D11</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-04" onclick="Historial('2016-11-04');">D12</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-05" onclick="Historial('2016-11-05');">D13</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-06" onclick="Historial('2016-11-06');">D14</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"><b><?php echo $semanas[2]?></b></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-07" onclick="Historial('2016-11-07');">D15</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-08" onclick="Historial('2016-11-08');">D16</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-09" onclick="Historial('2016-11-09');">D17</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-10" onclick="Historial('2016-11-10');">D18</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-11" onclick="Historial('2016-11-11');">D19</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-12" onclick="Historial('2016-11-12');">D20</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-13" onclick="Historial('2016-11-13');">D21</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"><b><?php echo $semanas[3]?></b></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-14" onclick="Historial('2016-11-14');">D22</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-15" onclick="Historial('2016-11-15');">D23</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-16" onclick="Historial('2016-11-16');">D24</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-17" onclick="Historial('2016-11-17');">D25</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-18" onclick="Historial('2016-11-18');">D26</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-19" onclick="Historial('2016-11-19');">D27</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-20" onclick="Historial('2016-11-20');">D28</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"><b><?php echo $semanas[4]?></b></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-21" onclick="Historial('2016-11-21');">D29</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-22" onclick="Historial('2016-11-22');">D30</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-23" onclick="Historial('2016-11-23');">D31</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-24" onclick="Historial('2016-11-24');">D32</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-25" onclick="Historial('2016-11-25');">D33</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-26" onclick="Historial('2016-11-26');">D34</div>  
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-27" onclick="Historial('2016-11-27');">D35</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"><b><?php echo $semanas[5]?></b></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-28" onclick="Historial('2016-11-28');">D36</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-29" onclick="Historial('2016-11-29');">D37</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-11-30" onclick="Historial('2016-11-30');">D38</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-12-01" onclick="Historial('2016-12-01');">D39</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-12-02" onclick="Historial('2016-12-02');">D40</div>
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-12-03" onclick="Historial('2016-12-03');">D41</div> 
                <div class="btnDiaRedondo" id="2016-12-04" onclick="Historial('2016-12-04');">D42</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Error -->
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px; background: #e6e6e6; color: #fff;" id="errorHistorial">
        <div class="" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 100px;">
            <h1 style="color: #444444;">
                AÚN NO TIENES RESULTADOS PARA MOSTRAR ESTE DÍA
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Error -->
    <!-- Mente -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="historialMente">
    </div>
    <!-- Mente -->            
    <!-- Cuerpo -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="historialCuerpo">
    </div>
    <!-- Cuerpo -->
    <!-- Energia -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="historialEnergia">
    </div>
    <!-- Energia -->
</div>      
<!-- Historial -->
</section>
```

Los `btnDiaRedondo` mandan a un archivo llamado *scripts2.php* un comando que hace al historial esconder una parte de la página para luego traerse los datos que contiene el botón en el "*onclick*".

El problema empieza justo cuando arranca  `$(document).ready(function(){ $.ajax({.` El ajax no corre debido a que el *console.log* no se activa.

```
    function Historial(data){   
        var f = new Date();
        var getdate = f.getDate();
        if(getdate >= 1 ||  getdate <= 9){
            getdates = '0'+getdate;
        }
        var fechaHoy = f.getFullYear()+"-"+(f.getMonth() +1)+"-"+getdates;

        if(data >= fechaHoy){
            $("#errorHistorial").fadeIn();
            $("#historialMente").empty();   
            $("#historialCuerpo").empty();   
            $("#historialEnergia").empty();   
            $("#2020-02-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2017-01-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-31").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-11-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-05").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-06").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-07").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-08").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-09").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-10").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-11").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-12").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-13").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-14").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-15").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-16").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-17").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-18").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-19").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-20").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-24").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-25").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-12-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-12-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 

            $("#2016-10-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-10-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-10-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");        

            fechaRetos = data;
            $("#"+fechaRetos).addClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");          
            return false;
        }else{
            $("#errorHistorial").fadeOut();
            $("#2020-02-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-25").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-31").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-11-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-05").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-06").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-07").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-08").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-09").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-10").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-11").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-12").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-13").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-14").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-15").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-16").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-17").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-18").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-19").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-20").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-24").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-25").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-12-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-12-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 

            $("#2016-10-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-10-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-10-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");        

            fechaRetos = data;
            $("#"+fechaRetos).addClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            console.log(fechaRetos);
            console.log("Tengo los datos");
            //Reto Mente
            $.ajax('function/puntosDAO.function2.php', { //Aqui empieza el problema
             method:"POST",
             data: {
               tipo: 'historialMente',
                hm_date: fechaRetos,
                registro_id: registro_id
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
             console.log(data);
             if(data.state == "ok") {
            console.log('Pase!');
            console.log(data);
             $("#historialMente").empty();
            var datHistorial = '<div class="retosTareas completo" style="padding-bottom:15px;"><h2><?php echo $labeldash[11]; ?></h2><div style="min-height: 150px;"><h4 style=""></h4></div><div style="min-height: 100px;"><span></span><br><br></div><div class=""><img src="images/hand.svg"></div><div style="text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: lighter;font-size: 26px; margin-top: 28px;"></div></div>';
            $("#historialMente").append(datHistorial);

    } else {
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax("function/puntosDAO.function2.php", {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                tipo: 'comprobarRetoMente',
                mente_date: fechaRetos,
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Falle");
            $("#historialMente").empty();
            var datHistorial = '<div class="retosTareas nocompleto" style="padding-bottom:55px;"><h2><?php echo $labeldash[11]; ?></h2><div style="min-height: 150px;"><h4 style=""></h4></div><div style="min-height: 100px;"><span></span><br><br></div><div class=""><img src="images/hand_no.svg"></div><div style="text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: lighter;font-size: 26px; margin-top: 28px;"><?php echo $final[3]; ?><br></div></div>';
            $("#historialMente").append(datHistorial);
        });
    }
});
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** El Header si manda los datos pero no hay ningun preview ni response...

Y el content length del header ahora es 54

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION:** Se logro hacer de que se pueda comunicar pero no revisa los datos bien, solo activa de que fallo

**ACTUALIZACION:** Se colocó los cambios que sugirió *Juan SA*, ahora solo muestra el mensaje de error.

Comment: Intenta quitando el **&** que tienes al inicio de esta línea: **data:"&tipo=historialMente**

Comment: No funciono, sigue igual

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes en `console.log(data)` en ambos casos?

Comment: Datos en blanco, no muestran datos

Comment: ¿El código es el real? En la captura de pantalla aparece que estás mandando una clave llamada **`he_date`** pero en ninguna de las peticiones Ajax aparece que estés mandando nada bajo esa clave, por lo que no entiendo por qué llega eso. ¿Podrías explicar de dónde sale ese `he_date`? Sería bueno también que agregues el código PHP que recibe y maneja los datos para ver cómo haces eso y qué respuesta emites.

Comment: he_date ya no se usa. Voy a actualizar

Comment: Explica cómo funciona el código ahora. Agrega también la parte `fail` a la petición Ajax para controlar los errores, dinos qué muestra la consolta exactamente. Otra cosa que no entiendo es por qué pasas la `url` sin usar el parámetro específico que tiene Ajax para eso. [Revisa la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), mira los ejemplos y estandariza tu código. Debes estar atento a la fiabilidad de las fuentes de las cuales aprendes, pues tu código no es estándar, no había visto hasta ahora peticiones Ajax con la url ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
$.ajax('function/puntosDAO.function2.php', { //Aqui empieza el problema
    method:"POST",
    data: {
        tipo: 'historialMente',
        hm_date: fechaRetos,
        registro_id: registro_id
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    if(data.state === "ok") {
        console.log("success");
        $("#historialMente").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function (i, item) {
            var intencion = item.intencion_note;
            var resintencion = intencion.slice(0, 20);
            var datHistorial = '<div class="retosTareas completo" style="padding-bottom:15px;"><h2><?php echo $labeldash[11]; ?></h2><div style="min-height: 150px;"><h4 style="">' + item.mente_label + '</h4></div><div style="min-height: 100px;"><span>' + item.mente_reto + '</span><br><br></div><div class=""><img src="images/hand.svg"></div><div style="text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: lighter;font-size: 26px; margin-top: 28px;"><?php echo $final[4]; ?> <span title="' + item.intencion_note + '">' + resintencion + '...</span><br><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 10px;"><?php echo $final[1]; ?> ' + item.mente_puntos + ' <?php echo $final[2]; ?></p></div></div>';

            $("#historialMente").append(datHistorial);

        });

    } else {
        $.ajax("function/puntosDAO.function2.php", {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                tipo:  'comprobarRetoMente',
                mente_date: fechaRetos,
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log("fallo");
            $("#historialMente").empty();
            $.each(data.result, function(i, item){
                var datHistorial = '<div class="retosTareas nocompleto" style="padding-bottom:55px;"><h2><?php echo $labeldash[11]; ?></h2><div style="min-height: 150px;"><h4 style="">'+item.mente_label+'</h4></div><div style="min-height: 100px;"><span>'+item.mente_reto+'</span><br><br></div><div class=""><img src="images/hand_no.svg"></div><div style="text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: lighter;font-size: 26px; margin-top: 28px;"><?php echo $final[3]; ?><br></div></div>';
                $("#historialMente").append(datHistorial);

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Da "Illegal invocation"

Comment: perdon, creo que historialMente debe de ir entre comillas, ya estaeditado

Comment: Es un avance, pero solo el console log de "fallo" se activa mas no hace el resto

Comment: Me deshice de una funcion que estaba demas y ahora solo se activa de que no se completo

Comment: data: {
          tipo: 'historialMente',
          hm_date: fechaRetos,
          registro_id: registro_id
        } Manda los datos vacios...

Comment: Probaste agregando al ajax?
 dataType: "json",